# Xamarin.Mac dock icon does not accept drag and drop files

Tags: c#, viewcontroller, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

My application does not accept drag and drop files on the Dock icons like other applications.

[image]

For example, the dock icon in Visual Studio for Mac accepts the file, but when I build and run the default project, it does not accept the drag and drop of the dock icon.

Perhaps I need to configure something in Xcode, but how can I do that?

Also, what kind of code should I write to receive the file path dragged and dropped to the dock icon in `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

First, open the `info.plist` in your project and click the `Advanced` tab in the bottom of window, and then `Add Document Type` button.

[image]

Select `Document` in `Class` item, and for `Identifier`, enter `public.item`. For `Role`, set it to `None`.

[image]

Then you will be able to drag and drop it to the Dock icon.

[image]

Then write the code can receive the dragged and dropped files in the program side.

**`AppDelegate.cs`**

```cs
public override void OpenUrls(NSApplication application, NSUrl[] urls)
{
  //base.OpenUrls(application, urls);
  var alert = new NSAlert();
  alert.MessageText = "AppDelegate.OpenUrls()";
  alert.InformativeText = urls[0].AbsoluteString;
  alert.AddButton("Ok");
  alert.RunModal();
}
```

ref. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/158538/xamarin-mac-appdelegate-openurls-not-invoked

Now you can receive and view the information about the dragged and dropped files.

[image]